# C - error conflicting types for function

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I'm trying to get a lot of text from the user and count the number of words, characters, lines, whitespaces and letters. This is what I've done:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c = getchar();
    char previousc;
    int charcount = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int whitespacecount = 0;
    int linecount = 0;
    int lettercount = 0;
    while(c != EOF)
    {
            if(isLetter(c) == 1) lettercount++;
            if(isWhitespace(c) == 1)
            {
                    whitespacecount++;
                    if(isWhitespace(previousc) == 0) wordcount++;
            }
            if(c == "\n") linecount++;
            previousc = c;
            c = getchar();
            charcount++;
    }
    printf("Character Count: %d\n Word Count: %d\n Whitespace Count: %d\n Letter Count: %d\n Line Count: %d\n", charcount, wordcount, whitespacecount, linecount, lettercount);
}
int isLetter(char c) // 1 for true, 0 for false.
{
    // instead of writing tons of if's
    if(isalpha(c) > 0)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
int isWhitespace(char c) // 1 for true, 0 for false.
{
    if(c == "\n" || c == " " || c == "      ") return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But I get so many errors and warnings I'm just lost...

```
program2.c: In function ‘main’:
program2.c:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
program2.c: At top level:
program2.c:28: error: conflicting types for ‘isLetter’
program2.c:28: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
program2.c:14: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘isLetter’ was here
program2.c:35: error: conflicting types for ‘isWhitespace’
program2.c:35: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
program2.c:15: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘isWhitespace’ was here
program2.c: In function ‘isWhitespace’:
program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

I googled the different errors but didn't find a solution that solves my problem.

Can you help me a bit?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `c == "\n"` to `c == '\n'`

Comment: @ouah, thanks, that solved the comparison between pointer and integer problem.

Comment: Declare your functions *before* you use them. So either put prototypes of `isLetter` and `isWhitespace` before your `main`, or move the functions altogether. Also you may want to look at some of the functions in [`ctype.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

Comment: your function `isWhitespace` will not work! there you are also comparing `char`'s with `char *`'s. i would write it like `int isWhitespace(char c){ return (c==' ')||(c=='\t')||(c=='\n'); }` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For

> program2.c:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Change

```
 if(c == "\n")
```

to

```
 if(c == '\n')
```

For

> program2.c:28: error: conflicting types for ‘isLetter’
>   program2.c:28: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty   parameter name list declaration
>   program2.c:14: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘isLetter’ was here
>   program2.c:35: error: conflicting types for ‘isWhitespace’
>   program2.c:35: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty   parameter name list declaration
>   program2.c:15: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘isWhitespace’ was here

Define prototypes for your functions.

```
int isLetter(char c);
int isWhitespace(char c);
```

For

> program2.c: In function ‘isWhitespace’:
>   program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>   program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>   program2.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Change

```
if(c == "\n" || c == " " || c == "      ") return 1;
```

to

```
if(c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t')
```

Comment: Of course one *should* declare functions with a prototype.  Otherwise, they say, the compiler will do an implicit declaration, assuming the return type is int.

But in this specific case that's exactly right!  So why the error?
What implicit declaration did the compiler infer on line 14??

Answer (score 2):

Start with the first error/warning, fix it and then work your way down one by one always compiling after each change. Often, you will find, getting rid of an error/warning on a line also gets rid of others in subsequent lines.

Line 20:

```
            if(c == "\n") linecount++;
```

gives the warning

```
program2.c:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

`c` is a char (internally converted to an integer before the comparison); `"\n"` is an array[2] of `char` (internally converted to `char *` before the comparison).
That's why the compiler complains about comparing an integer and a pointer.

You need to compare `c` to a character (both will get internally converted to integers)

```
            if(c == '\n') linecount++;
```

Answer (score 2):

- Declare the following functions **before** calling them (i.e., above function `main`):

  - `int isLetter(char c);`
  - `int isWhitespace(char c);`

---

- In function `main`:

  - Replace the variable-declaration  `char c`          with `int c`
  - Replace the function-call         `isLetter(c)`     with `isLetter((char)c)`
  - Replace the function-call         `isWhitespace(c)` with `isWhitespace((char)c)`
  - Replace the variable-assignment   `previous = c`    with `previous = (char)c`
  - Replace the conditional-statement `if (c == "\n")`  with `if ((char)c == '\n')`

The reason for `int c`, is that function `getchar` returns `int` in order support the `EOF` indicator.

---

- In function `isWhitespace`, change the conditional-statement to:

  - `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t')`

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` is an integer value which indicate the end of input. It's a value such that for any character `ch`, `ch == EOF` is always false. Therefore, you should always compare a value of `int` type with `EOF`, not `char` type. It's working on your machine because the `char` type is implemented as `signed char` but on machines where `char` type is `unsigned char`, this won't.

Now coming to the warnings and errors

1. The scope of a function is from the point of its definition or declaration till the end of the program. You are calling the functions like `isLetter` in `main` before they have been declared.
2. `"\n"` is a string literal, not a character. So are `" "` and `"    "`. The string literal here evaluates to a pointer to its first element and you are comparing this pointer with a character -  a different type. You should, instead, compare with `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the function header before using it in the main, for example:

```
int isLetter(char c);
int main(void){
char c = getchar();
char previousc;
int charcount = 0;
int wordcount = 0;
int whitespacecount = 0;
int linecount = 0;
int lettercount = 0;
while(c != EOF)
{
        if(isLetter(c) == 1) lettercount++;
        if(isWhitespace(c) == 1)
        {
                whitespacecount++;
                if(isWhitespace(previousc) == 0) wordcount++;
        }
        if(c == "\n") linecount++;
        previousc = c;
        c = getchar();
        charcount++;
}
printf("Character Count: %d\n Word Count: %d\n Whitespace Count: %d\n Letter Count: %d\n Line Count: %d\n", charcount, wordcount, whitespacecount, linecount, lettercount);}
```

that will fix the conflicting types error. 
but also you'll have to change " " to ' ' if you are checking on characters.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you highlight how your answer differs or adds to the others already on this 2-year-old post, please?