# Difficulties installing ruby18_source_location for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having difficulties installing `ruby18_source_location`, and I'm relatively new to ruby. So... does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this problem? I'm trying to do a `bundle install` in a rails application.

At first, I tried installing the package via:

```
$ gem install ruby18_source_location
```

But that failed. Then I git cloned this package: https://github.com/ConradIrwin/ruby18_source_location

When I tried to  build from source, I got the same error as I got when I ran `gem install`:

```
gcc -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I.   -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o ruby18_source_location.o -c ruby18_source_location.c
In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:362:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_NONE" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_NONE     0x00

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2055:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_NONE      0x0000

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:363:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_LINE" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_LINE     0x01

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2056:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_LINE      0x0001

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:364:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_CLASS" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_CLASS    0x02

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2057:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_CLASS     0x0002

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:365:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_END" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_END      0x04

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2058:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_END       0x0004

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:366:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_CALL" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_CALL     0x08

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2059:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_CALL      0x0008

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:367:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_RETURN" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_RETURN   0x10

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2060:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_RETURN    0x0010

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:368:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_C_CALL" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_C_CALL   0x20

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2061:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_C_CALL    0x0020

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:369:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_C_RETURN" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_C_RETURN 0x40

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2062:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_C_RETURN  0x0040

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:370:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_RAISE" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_RAISE    0x80

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2063:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_RAISE     0x0080

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:371:0: warning: "RUBY_EVENT_ALL" redefined
 #define RUBY_EVENT_ALL      0xff

In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2064:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_EVENT_ALL       0x00ff

In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:373:16: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_event_hook_func_t’
 typedef void (*rb_event_hook_func_t) _((rb_event_t,NODE*,VALUE,ID,VALUE));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2093:16: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_event_hook_func_t’ was here
 typedef void (*rb_event_hook_func_t)(rb_event_flag_t evflag, VALUE data, VALUE self, ID mid, VALUE klass);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:375:6: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_add_event_hook’
 void rb_add_event_hook _((rb_event_hook_func_t,rb_event_t));
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2096:6: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_add_event_hook’ was here
 void rb_add_event_hook(rb_event_hook_func_t func, rb_event_flag_t events, VALUE data);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ruby18_source_location.c:2:0:
node.h:376:5: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_remove_event_hook’
 int rb_remove_event_hook _((rb_event_hook_func_t));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:2097:5: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_remove_event_hook’ was here
 int rb_remove_event_hook(rb_event_hook_func_t func);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from node.h:383:0,
                 from ruby18_source_location.c:2:
/usr/include/ruby/backward/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h" [-Wcpp]
 #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
  ^~~~~~~
ruby18_source_location.c: In function ‘method_source_location’:
ruby18_source_location.c:90:19: warning: unused variable ‘block’ [-Wunused-variable]
     struct BLOCK *block;
                   ^~~~~
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'ruby18_source_location.o' failed
make: *** [ruby18_source_location.o] Error 1
```

Like I said, I'm a novice at ruby. I couldn't find any solutions online that pertain to this specific issue.

I saw some suggestions about uninstalling middleman, then installing this package, then reinstalling middleman. I tried that and that didn't work. :(

Comment: a) It might be a silly question, but which version of Ruby are you using? And on which OS? b) Why not just use a newer Ruby? 1.8.7 has been [retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) three years ago.

Comment: I agree with Amadan. Also, there are errors in the C code, perhaps because the gem is 4 years old. I found a Stack Overflow question covering one of the errors (conflicting types for function) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436975/c-error-conflicting-types-for-function